# jQuery selectors on custom data attributes using HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, custom-data-attribute

I would like to know what selectors are available for these data attributes that come with HTML5.

Taking this piece of HTML as an example:

```
<ul data-group="Companies">
  <li data-company="Microsoft"></li>
  <li data-company="Google"></li>
  <li data-company ="Facebook"></li>
</ul>
```

Are there selectors to get:

- All elements with `data-company="Microsoft"` below `"Companies"`
- All elements with `data-company!="Microsoft"` below `"Companies"`
- In other cases is it possible to use other selectors like "contains, less than, greater than, etc...".

Comment: If you look here you will find all you need http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ :-)

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2487747/1066234

Answer (score 1137, accepted):

```
$("ul[data-group='Companies'] li[data-company='Microsoft']") //Get all elements with data-company="Microsoft" below "Companies"

$("ul[data-group='Companies'] li:not([data-company='Microsoft'])") //get all elements with data-company!="Microsoft" below "Companies"
```

Look in to [jQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) :contains is a selector

here is info on the [:contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

Comment: will this work?
`$('div[data-col="1"][data-row="2"]')`

Will this select the div where data-col equals 1 and data-row equals 2, or will it select on either of those?

Comment: Will this work if data is set via .data('something',value)? Often this does not create an actual attribute when attaching the value.  I know the OP was pretty specific regarding attributes, but thought I'd raise awareness in case others have issue with this selector.

Comment: @AaronLS No it doesn't (at least not with older versions of jQuery eg. 1.4.4) - you need to set the data using `.attr('data-something', 'value')` to see the update in the HTML. As per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827810/unable-to-set-data-attribute-using-jquery-data-api

Comment: Isn't there a way to get data attribute values without typing `data` in the call?

Comment: @gwho `$('#element').data('something')`

Comment: I want to add the note: That syntax can be used for any html attribute.

Comment: John, I like your explanations because in example used Microsoft like NOT in selection

Comment: We don't need to use quotes for those values in the custom data attribute. We can use like this `$("ul[data-group=Companies] li[data-company=Microsoft]")`.

Answer (score 78):

`jQuery UI` has a [`:data()` selector](http://api.jqueryui.com/data-selector/) which can also be used. It has been around since [Version 1.7.0](http://jqueryui.com/changelog/1.7/) it seems.

You can use it like this:

**Get all elements with a `data-company` attribute**

```
var companyElements = $("ul:data(group) li:data(company)");
```

**Get all elements where `data-company` equals `Microsoft`**

```
var microsoft = $("ul:data(group) li:data(company)")
                    .filter(function () {
                        return $(this).data("company") == "Microsoft";
                    });
```

**Get all elements where `data-company` does not equal `Microsoft`**

```
var notMicrosoft = $("ul:data(group) li:data(company)")
                       .filter(function () {
                           return $(this).data("company") != "Microsoft";
                       });
```

*etc...*

One caveat of the new `:data()` selector is that you must set the `data` value *by code* for it to be selected. This means that for the above to work, defining the `data` in HTML is not enough. You must first do this:

```
$("li").first().data("company", "Microsoft");
```

This is fine for single page applications where you are likely to use `$(...).data("datakey", "value")` in this or similar ways.

Comment: I don't get your caveat. This works fine for me, and I make no other reference to data in the js.

$('#id').text($('#mydatasource').data('empty'));

This will populate the #id element with the contents of the data-empty tag on the #mydatasource element.

Comment: @FacebookAnswers Did you use the `:data()` selector, or the `.data()` method?

Comment: I see what you mean. I was using the method, whereas your caveat referred to the method.

Comment: ^you mean his caveat referred to the selector.

Comment: `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: data` with Jquery 3.

Comment: @KaiNoack Could you please provide some sample code? If needed, it may be good to ask a separate question.

Comment: Weird, now it seems to work in the fiddle with Jquery 3.3.1: http://jsfiddle.net/kai_noack/q6nzLs20/1/

Comment: @Avatar The `:data()` selector is from **jQueryUI**, it's not in jQuery. That's why you get that syntax error. In the fiddle you are using the data attribute selector `ul[data-group]` which is a CSS selector and it works with jQuery (and the one used in the accepted answer).

Answer (score 49):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/sxpLe9vv/)***

jQuery provides several [selectors (full list)](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) in order to make the queries you are looking for work. To address your question *"In other cases is it possible to use other selectors like "contains, less than, greater than, etc..."."* you can also use contains, starts with, and ends with to look at these html5 data attributes. See the full list above in order to see all of your options.

The basic querying has been covered above, and using [John Hartsock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/254528/john-hartsock)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4146566/1026459) is going to be the best bet to either get every data-company element, or to get every one except Microsoft (or any other version of `:not`).

In order to expand this to the other points you are looking for, we can use several meta selectors. First, if you are going to do multiple queries, it is nice to cache the parent selection.

```
var group = $('ul[data-group="Companies"]');
```

Next, we can look for companies in this set who start with G

```
var google = $('[data-company^="G"]',group);//google
```

Or perhaps companies which contain the word soft

```
var microsoft = $('[data-company*="soft"]',group);//microsoft
```

It is also possible to get elements whose data attribute's ending matches

```
var facebook = $('[data-company$="book"]',group);//facebook
```

```js
//stored selector
var group = $('ul[data-group="Companies"]');

//data-company starts with G
var google = $('[data-company^="G"]',group).css('color','green');

//data-company contains soft
var microsoft = $('[data-company*="soft"]',group).css('color','blue');

//data-company ends with book
var facebook = $('[data-company$="book"]',group).css('color','pink');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul data-group="Companies">
  <li data-company="Microsoft">Microsoft</li>
  <li data-company="Google">Google</li>
  <li data-company ="Facebook">Facebook</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 7):

**Pure/vanilla JS solution** (working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/z9h3nsdf/9/))

```
// All elements with data-company="Microsoft" below "Companies"
let a = document.querySelectorAll("[data-group='Companies'] [data-company='Microsoft']"); 

// All elements with data-company!="Microsoft" below "Companies"
let b = document.querySelectorAll("[data-group='Companies'] :not([data-company='Microsoft'])");
```

In [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) you must use valid [CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) (currently [Level3](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/))

**SPEED TEST** (2018.06.29) for jQuery and Pure JS: test was performed on MacOs High Sierra 10.13.3 on Chrome 67.0.3396.99 (64-bit), Safari 11.0.3 (13604.5.6), Firefox 59.0.2 (64-bit). Below screenshot shows results for fastest browser (Safari):

[image]

PureJS was faster than jQuery about 12% on Chrome, 21% on Firefox and 25% on Safari. Interestingly speed for Chrome was 18.9M operation per second, Firefox 26M, Safari 160.9M (!).

**So winner is PureJS** and fastest browser is **Safari** (more than 8x faster than Chrome!)

Here you can perform test on your machine: https://jsperf.com/js-selectors-x