# Select td based on data attribute

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Jquery selectors on custom data attributes on HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146502/jquery-selectors-on-custom-data-attributes-on-html5)

How can I select all `td` with html data attribute equal to some value?

E.G. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smacky311/WbJdB/2/)

```
$("td").dblclick(function (e) {    
    var columnNumber = $(this).data('column');
    console.log(columnNumber);
    $("td column=" + columnNumber).css('background-color', 'blue');;
});
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

here is the good syntax :

```
$("td[data-column='"+columnNumber+"']")
```