# How can i use jquery to find an item by a different attribute than class?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, selector

I have the following html on a page:

```
<span class="descriptionLink" projectid="14180">
            Some text
</span>

<span class="descriptionLink" projectid="14181">
            Some text
</span>

<span class="descriptionLink" projectid="14182">
            Some text
</span>

<span class="descriptionLink" projectid="14182">
            Some text
</span>
```

and i want to grab the item with projectid = 14182 .  What is the right jquery syntax to grab this set of elements?

Comment: Use a standard attribute selector: `$("[projectid='14182']");`

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146502/jquery-selectors-on-custom-data-attributes-on-html5 is a better duplicate, searching would have found a lot of answers. Also, to be valid HTML, you should use `data-projectid` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seeing as `projectid` is an invalid element attribute, I'd say there's no right way to select on it. You'd be better off in HTML5 using

```
<span class="descriptionLink" data-projectid="14182">
```

and selecting off of `$('[data-projectid="14182"]')`

Or, alternatively, using classes:

```
<span class="descriptionLink projectid-14182">
```

Selecting like so:

```
var project_id_to_find = 14182;
$(".projectid-" + project_id_to_find);
```

Comment: when you say its an "invalid element" it seems to work in all browsers i have tried so what is "wrong" with it?

Comment: Browsers tend to be forgiving. In XML you'd be able to define all of your own attributes, but HTML isn't really the same way.
Here's the w3.org page on spans: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/span.html
and here is the list of <span>'s valid attributes: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html 
. Even though browsers may seem to support it, it's behavior is basically undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You can use attributes selector:

```
$('span[projectid=14182]')
```