# Jquery - Html Selectors to use except Id and Class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Are there any more than just a Id and Class -selectors to work with when using Jquery?

For example:

```
<div id="myId" class="myClass"></div>

<script>
    $('.myClass').click(function() {
        alert(this.id); //alerts my "myId"
    });
</script>
```

I want something like:

```
<div id="myId" data-id="myDataId" class="myClass"></div>

<script>
    $('.myClass').click(function() {
        alert(this.dataId);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146502/jquery-selectors-on-custom-data-attributes-on-html5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can different selectors like:

```
$( "div[data-id='myDataId']" );
```

and then:

```
$(this).attr("data-id")
```

or .data() (if you use newer jQuery >= 1.4.3)

```
$(this).data("id")
```

You can read it here: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/
http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
<div id="myId" data-id="myDataId" class="myClass"></div>

<script>
    $('.myClass').click(function() {
        alert($(this).data("id"));
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("[data-id=myDataId]")
```

JSfiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/sjj41box/1/