# Get element by id and custom attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have few elements like that:

```
<a id="0-interval-44" class="elem" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; display: none;" data-transformeffect="fade">text 1</a>
<a id="7-interval-15" class="elem" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; display: none;" data-transformeffect="slide">text 2</a>
<a id="7-interval-15" class="elem" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;  display: none;" data-transformeffect="fade">text 3</a>
```

And i need to get all elements by id and by `data-transformeffect` attribute. for example i need to get all element with `.id.indexOf('7-interval-') > -1` and with `.data.transformeffect() == 'fade'`.
This is necessary in order to apply different effects to different elements.

Comment: `$("[id*='7-interval-'][data-transformeffect=fade]")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Attribute Starts With Selector [name^="value"]`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) and [`Attribute Equals Selector[name="value"]`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
 var element = $('[ID^="7-interval-"][data-transformeffect=fade]')
```

Important, **IDs must be unique** you are using `7-interval-15` multiple times change it.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `data-transformeffect` instead of `data.transformeffect`?

Answer (score 0):

Use as

```
var a = $('a[id^="7-interval-"][data-transformeffect="fade"]')
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146502/jquery-selectors-on-custom-data-attributes-on-html5)

[Jquery Selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)