# Search div using data attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, undefined

Search elements based on data attributes. 
I have the following code and would like to know, how can this be achieved if the **data attribute value with space**

```
<div class="data" data-value="auto"> abcd </div>
<div class="data" data-value="simple tab,block"> acd </div>
<div class="data" data-value="auto"> abd </div>
<div class="data" data-value="block"> abcde </div>
<div class="null-data"> type the correct value </div>

<input class="search-text" name="keyword" type="text" id="search-keyword" placeholder="search">
```

On typing input value event I basically want to find out all the items that belong to a specific data-value?

```
$('#search-keyword').on( "keyup", function() {
$('.null-data').hide();
    if($(this).val()) {
        var input = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $(".data").hide();
        $(".data[data-value*="+ input +"]").show();
        if(!$('.data:visible').get(0)){
            $('.null-data').show();
        }
    }else{
        $('.null-data').show();     
    }
});
```

I'm getting the html elements based on data attribute values but if the **data attribute value has space**, the html elements are not showing up.

Comment: Attributes values must not include spaces, you can use underscore instead

Comment: If feels a very common question. Please search before ask: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146502/jquery-selectors-on-custom-data-attributes-on-html5

Comment: @JohnKapantzakis: What? Sure they can. Attribute values can be any string. Attribute *names*, of course, are another story.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

while building the selector, you need to wrap the input value in quote as in contents meta character in it :

```
$(".data[data-value*='"+ input +"']").show();
//-------------------^-----------^
    if(!$('.data:visible').get(0)){
        $('.null-data').show();
    }
```

**[Workin Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9m53ojo9/)**

Answer (score 0):

You are using incorrect syntax.

Replace your code to this

```
$('#search-keyword').on( "keyup", function() {
$('.null-data').hide();
    if($(this).val()) {
        var input = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $(".data").hide();
        $(".data[data-value*="+ input +"]").show();
        if(!$('.data:visible').get(0)){
            $('.null-data').show();
        }
    }else{
        $('.null-data').show();     
    }
});
```