# Best practice to store array of values in html attr?

Tags: javascript, html, attr

What is the best practice to store an array of values in a html (from php) attribute and later access them from javascript/jQuery?

```
<div class="storage" someAttr=?? /></div>
```

Its basically a simple array like `(code_1,code_2,code_3,...)`

Im thinking of doing a simple `someAttr="code_1;code_2;code_3"` and then exploding it:

```
      var a = $(this).attr('someAttr');
      (a.split(";")).forEach(function (attr){
        console.log(attr);
      });
```

Comment: `data` selectors, E.g: [jQuery selectors on custom data attributes using HTML5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146502/jquery-selectors-on-custom-data-attributes-using-html5)

Comment: You could try formatting it to JSON from PHP, then have JavaScript parse it.

Comment: I would like to go with [*data-attributes*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) introduced in HTML5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can `json_encode` your array on the PHP side, add it in as a `data-attribute` on the HTML side, and then parse it out on the JavaScript side.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        var jsArr = JSON.parse($('#phpArr').attr('data-attr'));
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <span id="phpArr" data-attr='<?php echo json_encode(arr); ?>'></span>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store like this in html attribute then you can split that into array using `JavaScript` with help of `Substring` functions

```
<li  id="P01[01]"></li>
```