# Associated action with data-id not id

Tags: jquery

I wish to be able to use data-id as an identifier on an action but am not sure how this is done. Usually for an id I would do the following:

```
$("#id").click.......
```

However I do not know the syntax to use data-id as the identifier. Something like this but not sure what:

```
$(data-id).click.....
```

Comment: `$('[data-id=dataidvalue]')` check [attr selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) for further infor

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery selectors on custom data attributes using HTML5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146502/jquery-selectors-on-custom-data-attributes-using-html5)

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[data-id='mydiv']").click(function() {
    alert($(this).text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-id="mydiv">click me div text</div>
```