# jQuery: find elements where data attribute is has a specific value

Tags: jquery, checkbox, toggle, switching

I have a master checkbox `Select all` along with a button to revert back to their original state to which there were loaded with. After the page is loaded I bind a data property to each of the checkboxes that if there were loaded as checked or un-checked.

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').each((i, e) => {
    if($(e).is(':checked'))
       $(e).data('default', true);
});

$('.js-select-all').on('mouseup', () => {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

I need to find the `checkboxes` where `data` property called `default` is `true` and mark them checked again.

```js
$('.js-revert').on('mouseup', () => {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').data('default', true).prop('checked', true);
});
```

I know it can be done with `each` loop and a `condition`. But the thing is that I'll have to go through all the checkboxes to do so. Therefore, I am looking for a faster way as there are already dozens of checkboxes in the application.

Comment: Hint.  `[type="checkbox"]` is used to find elements that have `type="checkbox"` on them.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this. And I have already tried this. But that way i have loop out each and every checkbox. I was looking a way to bypass that and straight to the checkbox with the attribute.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146502/jquery-selectors-on-custom-data-attributes-using-html5

Comment: No @Nikki9696, If i was adding the data attribute in the tag then it would have worked. But, I am working with data property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using just jQuery, there's no faster way to check the `.data()` stored in the checkboxes besides iterating over all of them.

But incase you're using [jQueryUI](https://api.jqueryui.com/data-selector/) you can use the `:data()` selector presented here:

https://api.jqueryui.com/data-selector/

which then you can use

`$(':checkbox:data(default)').prop('checked', true);`