# problem setting data attributes dynamically with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use data attributes to get some javascript to work:

```js
$('div#here').data('added', 'this was added');

const initial_actual = $('div#here').data('initial');
$('div#initial').text(initial_actual)
const initial_css_found = $('div#here[data-initial="this was already here"]');
$('div#initial').append(initial_css_found.length)


const added_actual = $('div#here').data('added');
$('div#added').text(added_actual);
const css_found = $("div#here[data-added='this was added']");
$('div#added').append(css_found.length)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="here" data-initial='this was already here'>
  div
</div>

<div id='initial'>
 dive
</div>

<div id='added'>
 dive
</div>
```

basically if I set data attributes dynamically using jquery, these don't seem to behave similarly to similar data attributes that were present in the html when loading the page.

- inspecting the generated HTML with my browser (Brave) the programmatically added data fields are not visible.
  [image]
- if I retrieve the data from a jquery object, the data contained is present.
- if I use a data selector ([as found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146502/jquery-selectors-on-custom-data-attributes-using-html5)) to get the element with the added data field, I get zero results

Answer (score 0):

ok, as the manual of jquery mentions [here](https://api.jquery.com/data/),

```
Using the data() method to update data does not affect attributes in the DOM.
To set a data-* attribute value, use attr.
```

so the solution is as follows:

```js
$('div#here').attr('data-added', 'this was added');

const initial_actual = $('div#here').data('initial');
$('div#initial').text(initial_actual)
const initial_css_found = $('div#here[data-initial="this was already here"]');
$('div#initial').append(initial_css_found.length)


const added_actual = $('div#here').data('added');
$('div#added').text(added_actual);
const css_found = $("div#here[data-added='this was added']");
$('div#added').append(css_found.length)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="here" data-initial='this was already here'>
  div
</div>

<div id='initial'>
 dive
</div>

<div id='added'>
 dive
</div>
```