# get data-group and convert to object in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I recieved `li` tag from `html`

```html
<li data-group="man">
    <span>15</span>
    <h5>alex</h5>
</li>
<li data-group="man">
    <span>20</span>
    <h5>jack</h5>
</li>
<li data-group="man">
    <span>30</span>
    <h5>john</h5>
</li>
<li data-group="woman">
    <span>25</span>
    <h5>Kianna</h5>
</li>
<li data-group="woman">
    <span>17</span>
    <h5>ela</h5>
</li>
<li data-group="woman">
    <span>25</span>
    <h5>Emery</h5>
</li>
```

I want to produce li using `foreach` and than convert them into an object if they have the same data-group.

```json
    "man":{
        "alex":15,
        "jack":20,
        "john":30
    },
    "woman":{
        "Kianna":25,
        "ela":17,
        "Emery":25
    }
```

Finally, they should be `assigned` to an empty object

**objects should not be as forms of 0,1,2...**

Comment: you can look at this answer which can be helpful [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146502/jquery-selectors-on-custom-data-attributes-using-html5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`document.querySelectorAll('[data-group]')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get all items with a `[data-group]` tag. Spread the [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) to an array, and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) the array to the object:

```js
const result = [...document.querySelectorAll('[data-group]')]
  .reduce((acc, el) => ({
    ...acc,
    [el.dataset.group]: {
      ...acc[el.dataset.group],
      [el.children[1].textContent]: +el.children[0].textContent
    }
  }), {})
  
console.log(result)
```

```css
ul { visibility: hidden; }
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<ul> <li data-group="man"> <span>15</span> <h5>alex</h5> </li><li data-group="man"> <span>20</span> <h5>jack</h5> </li><li data-group="man"> <span>30</span> <h5>john</h5> </li><li data-group="woman"> <span>25</span> <h5>Kianna</h5> </li><li data-group="woman"> <span>17</span> <h5>ela</h5> </li><li data-group="woman"> <span>25</span> <h5>Emery</h5> </li></ul>
```

You can also use [`NodeList.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) to create the object:

```js
const result = {}

document.querySelectorAll('[data-group]')
  .forEach(el => {
    const { group } = el.dataset
    const [value, key] = el.children
    
    if(!result[group]) result[group] = {}
    
    result[group][key.textContent] = +value.textContent
  })
  
console.log(result)
```

```css
ul { visibility: hidden; }
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<ul> <li data-group="man"> <span>15</span> <h5>alex</h5> </li><li data-group="man"> <span>20</span> <h5>jack</h5> </li><li data-group="man"> <span>30</span> <h5>john</h5> </li><li data-group="woman"> <span>25</span> <h5>Kianna</h5> </li><li data-group="woman"> <span>17</span> <h5>ela</h5> </li><li data-group="woman"> <span>25</span> <h5>Emery</h5> </li></ul>
```