# filtering data based on a custom data attribute using jquery

Tags: jquery, filtering, custom-data-attribute

I was wondering if someone could help with with some jquery code for doing the following.
I have a drop down select list input that i would like to filter a list of checkboxes.

Here's what my html code looks like

```
 <span style="float:right;">

        <label>Filter</label> 
    <select id="office-type-list" name="OfficeTypes"><option value="00">All</option>

        <option value="05">Township</option>

        <option value="10">Municipality</option>

        <option value="15">Elementary School</option>

        <option value="20">High School</option>

    </select> 

</span>

<!-- List below -->

<div name="Offices">
    <div data-custom-type="00">
        <input type="checkbox" name="Offices" id="Offices_0000" value="0000" /> <label for="Offices_0000">All</label>
    </div>
    <div data-custom-type="05">
        <input type="checkbox" name="Offices" id="Offices_0010" value="0010" /> <label for="Offices_0010">Township 1p</label>
    </div>
    <div data-custom-type="05">
        <input type="checkbox" name="Offices" id="Offices_0020" value="0020" /> <label for="Offices_0020">Township 2</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

So if Township is selected (05) then only the divs with the data-custom-type="05" will display.

Is there a way to achieve this and if so some help would be much appreciated

Comment: first of all `data-custom-type` should be `data-r` unless you are using HTML5 only. it might fail on older browsers. second thing, a div cannot have a name, name is only for inputs, change name to id.

Comment: The answer you selected fails for choosing an item and then choosing 'All'. When doing this, only 'All' shows, not all of the original divs/checkboxes. My answer handles that case as well.

Comment: you're absolutely correct. i've gone ahead and updated my accepted answer. thanks.

Comment: actually i was a bit fuzzy on the details because i included all as an option in the list of offices. my bad

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter element based on .data() key/value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009485/filter-element-based-on-data-key-value)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DpZdp/)** to test.

```
$('#office-type-list').change(function(){
    var sel = $(this).val();
    $('div[name="Offices"] div').hide();
    if(sel != "00"){
       $('div[data-custom-type="'+sel+'"]').show();
    }
    else {
        $('div[name="Offices"] div').show();
    }
});
```

If "All" is selected, all the options are displayed, otherwise only the matching elements are displayed.

Answer (score 7):

You could do something like:

```
$("#office-type-list").change(function() {
    var customType = $(this).val();
    $("div[name=Offices]").children("div").hide().filter(function() {
        return $(this).data("custom-type") == customType;
    }).show();
});
```

The code above handles the `change` event of your `<select>` element by matching the `<div>` elements that are direct children of your main `Offices` element, hiding them all, then applying [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to obtain the children whose `data-custom-type` attributes match the selected value, and showing these.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
$("#office-type-list").change(function(){
     $("div[data-custom-type]").hide();
     $("div[data-custom-type=" + this.value +"]").show();
});
```