# trying to remove div tag based on data attribute

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="row-container" data-i="'+data[i].product_id+'">
<div class="row-container" data-i="'+data[i].product_id+'">
<div class="row-container" data-i="'+data[i].product_id+'">
<div class="row-container" data-i="'+data[i].product_id+'">
```

I want to delete the row-container that contains a particular product_id. I know data('i') retrieves the value, but I dont know where to go from there.

Comment: Related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009485/jquery-filter-element-based-on-data-key-value

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
$('.row-container').filter(function(){
    return $(this).data('i') === "product_id"
}).remove();
```

`.data` allows you to set and get other variables beside of strings (functions and objects)

You can also use this:

```
$('.row-container').filter('[data-i="product_id"]').remove();
```

Or with one selector:

```
$('.row-container[data-i="product_id"]').remove();
```

(Where `"product_id"` is a placeholder for the real value...)

Comment: +1 Just change `"foo"` to `"product_id"` for clarity. Also isn't the last too faster?

Comment: @iambriansreed. Probably yes... but it's a minor change.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `filter()`:

```
var $div = $(".row-container").filter(function() {
    return $(this).data("i") == value; // where value == product id to find
});
$div.remove();
```

Comment: @iambriansreed true, but I like to make my answers as clear as possible.

Answer (score 5):

There's an [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) in jQuery that you could use to find the element that you're looking for.

```
$('div.row-container[data-i="<value>"]');
```